# Can a PC cast a Floor of force?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

The [PRD entry for environment](http://paizo.com/prd/environment.html) states:

> **Transparent Floor:** Transparent floors, made of reinforced glass or magic materials (even a wall of force) [...]

The [PRD entry for Wall of Force](http://paizo.com/prd/spells/wallOfForce.html) states:

> The caster can form the wall into a flat, vertical plane whose area is up to one 10-foot square per level. The wall must be continuous and unbroken when formed. If its surface is broken by any object or creature, the spell fails.

If interpreting RAW for the entire ruleset, is there any way a can PC caster create bridges/umbrellas/ramps using this spell? Or is there a different spell for planes of force at other angles?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

RAW, no. The spell specifically says 'vertical' so unless your 'floor' is a wall, you cannot use it as a bridge.

Look at the wording for 'wall of iron': http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/w/wall-of-iron

> You cause a flat, vertical iron wall to spring into being.

And now look at 'wall of stone':  http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/w/wall-of-stone

> Unlike a wall of iron, you can create a wall of stone in almost any
>   shape you desire. The wall created need not be vertical, nor rest upon
>   any firm foundation;

Comment: I know at the least that in *Dungeons & Dragons* this was an intentional limitation of the spell, which was sometimes commented upon in magazine articles and the like.

Comment: Taking up the whole 10-foot square and being "flat" seems contradictory to me...

Comment: @izkata In this case "flat" means "has no bumps or protrusions on its surface" instead of "is thin like paper."

Comment: @AceCalhoon In that case, can't you use the 10-foot square top surface as "floor", contradicting ColinD's answer?

Comment: @izkata I think we both misread different parts of it. You're right in that it's flat like paper. But it doesn't take up 10'x10' on the battle grid. It takes up 10'x0'x10'... I.e., it is a vertical plane of depth 0', height 10', and width 10'. You'd draw it on the map as a line.

Comment: Presumably, some wizard developed a "floor of force" spell that he thought would take off, but as it never quite got off the ground, he ended up working at his cousin's dungeon renovation company.

Comment: RAW, no. I've always house-ruled a "yes", though, simply because one of the first campaigns I ever DM'd, I wanted to use one cast thus and permanentized as a plot device, and I've since found them handy to have available, and never found any particular problem with allowing them.